# Running PHP in Putty gives 'Could not open input file'

Tags: php, apache, command-line, putty

In Putty command line I write

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/folder/file.php
```

Also try

```
php /var/www/html/folder/file.php
```

Both give 'Could not open input file'

The permisson for file is 777. Operational system is UNIX

PHP script:

```
<?php

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: CRON';

mail('admin@website.com','CRON',"<b>THIS IS SIMULATION TEST</b>",$headers);


?>
```

Comment: Sorry to ask the stupid question, but did you verify that the file is actually there? Also, maybe try accessing using a relative path.

Comment: Yes). In addition to that I can run it through the browser

Comment: And what about using relative path? I.e., if you cd into /var/www/html/folder and run it from there.

Comment: Yes! relative path works. What should I do now? I want to add this path in cronjob

Comment: You can add the relative path in the cron job.

Comment: 5 * * * * php file.php  Like this? ))

Comment: Is it possible to cd folder and run php in one command? Without a bash

Comment: Could you show it, writing fully what I wrote above? I don't know what is ls -lah

Comment: What should I write after ls -lah? the name of file?

Comment: Could you show you php script ?

Comment: Edited, adding above.

Comment: I can run the script via relative path. I can't do it using absolute path

Comment: I can't think of any reason why that would happen. There must be a typo in the absolute path.

Comment: cd the path works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sometimes happens when you have Windows newline endings (\r\n) instead of Unix style (\n) inside the **PHP** or **cron** file.

**Fix: convert line endings to Unix style**

`dos2unix /var/www/html/folder/file.php`

**or**

`sed -i 's/\r//' /var/www/html/folder/file.php`

**or**

Use an editor such as [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to convert EOL:

1. open the file in Notepad++
2. double-click "Dos/Windows" in the bottom right corner
3. change to "UNIX/OSX format"
4. save, upload and test

.

Remember, do this for both the PHP file and file holding your cron commands.

Comment: I don't have any newline endings. Just 1 line of file address

Comment: Do you have the #!/usr/bin/php line at the top of the .php file?

Comment: And I mean newline endings in the PHP file, not in the command line.

Comment: The system can't open file itself. Are you sure that newlines in php file may cause this error?

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/php line at the top of the .php file` is not needed

Comment: It's not needed, but if he has it (then just one line of PHP code) it still might be the cause of newline char issue.

Comment: @TarlanMamedzadeh only one way to find out... try it.

Comment: The php file has several lines. However I use Notetab++.

Comment: How should I change the newlines?

Comment: See my answer, I updated it with three possible ways (two from command line, one from Notepad++)

Comment: I don't think PHP cares what kind of newlines the file has. It would be an issue if you just tried to run the PHP script as a command and depended on the `#!` line, but not when you run `php filename`.

Comment: Using that commands give 'Can't read the file'. But ls command shows the file

Comment: I CAN RUN PHP VIA RELATIVE PATH! I CAN'T VIA ABSOLUTE PATH

Comment: @TarlanMamedzadeh No need to SHOUT

Comment: I did 2 things. Opened crontab -e with sudo and then did what you said. It worked! Thanks.

Comment: I was just about to say that perhaps you have the wrong newlines in the CRON file :)  Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Use relative path. I.e., if you cd into /var/www/html/folder and run it from there.

Comment: I need to run it via absolute path. As it will be run by cronjob

Comment: I see that, I think @Tarlan answered in the comments.

Comment: Now, it is)))))

Comment: Sorry, I meant @jay answered in the comments.